# Dense convex set in $*$-weak topology

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space over $\mathbb{K}$. Suppose $W$ is a convex subset of its topological dual $X'$. How to prove that if for any $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ set $\{f(x):f\in W\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{K}$ then $\overline{W}^{\sigma(X',X)}=X'$ ?

Comment: You need $x\neq 0$, for $x = 0$ we have $\{f(x) : f\in W\} = \{0\}$. Use (one of) the Hahn-Banach separation theorem(s).

Comment: So, suppose there is $f_0\notin \overline{W}^{\sigma(X',X)}$. Then there exists $\xi\in X''$ s.th. $\xi\left(\overline{W}^{\sigma(X',X)}\right)<\xi(f_0)$. But $\{f(x):f\in W\}\subset \xi(W)$, hence $\{f(x):f\in W\}$ cannot be dense in $\mathbb{K}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: You need $\xi = x$. But you're looking at $(X',\sigma(X',X))$, and $(X',\sigma(X',X))' = X$.